# Angular 9+ detect module route is protected

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, router

I am blocked somewhere, developing a Core Library for my Org.
The library is used in other microservices(a website with lots of pages or app) which take care of some basic stuff like Authentication, Profiling and Impersonation etc and then also if the app/website is running on MS teams.
This microservices might have some pages which are guarded and some not.

Problem: Given a link of a page, I would like to know whether that route/link is guarded or not. Guarded means `canActivate` of Angular route.

Case: I have a link i.e. example.com/app_name/protected_module/route_1, and I would like to know whether the module `protected_module/route1` is protected or not.

Some more info: I am using `APP_INITIALIZER` because it checks if the page needs authentication or not. In order to detect whether it needs authentication, I would like to know first the current route has `canActivate` or not. If it has then I can start authentication process, otherwise shows the page.

Current working solution: Load all lazy routes/modules and then, match the current route and check it has the `canActivate` object or not. It works fine, but It's not the proper way because you are waiting for all the routes to fetch (done with a lots of promises and recursive).

Other Solution Tried: In order to check directly, I tested this piece of code from SO `this.router.config.find(f => f.path === this.router.url.substr(1))` and it works fine on bootstrap routes (the first layer/app-routing.modules.ts routes) i.e. example.com/home but on `example.com/app_name/protected_module/route_1` gives undefined.

Sorry in adv, I am bad at explaining and tried my best to explain the problem. Please help and if you need more info ask me. Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't you just edit `canActivate` to start authentication as part of the auth guard? ie. if they are not signed in, redirect to authenticate, save the original route, and redirect back after authentication. That's how auth guards are intended to be used. Hence why they're called authentication guards.

Comment: CanActivate is triggered after the APP_INITILIZER. But I need it before in order to have the user profile and preset some values so the apps can use it.

Comment: So you're presetting some values for only the routes that need `canActivate`? So you could just set those values with a service and fetch them in `canActivate`, or in the component no? Maybe you should explain exactly what you're trying to do, because it seems like you might have an approach that was not intended by the Angular devs.